# ldap_simple_bind: Invalid credentials

Tags: ldap

I'm trying a `ldapsearch`.

The user is "domain\user" and the connection and bind is successfull with `ApacheDirectoryStudio` (see image), however I don't understand how to use the -D parameter in ldapsearch (maybe the problem is the bachslash ?).

I've tried with:

```
ldapsearch -h IT.xxxx.COM -D "CN=domain\user,DC=it,DC=xxxx,DC=com" -w Password -b base 'objectClass=*'
```

but I get the error:

> ldap_simple_bind: Invalid credentials  --- 80090308: LdapErr:
>   DSID-0C090400, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e

Thanks for help.
Giuseppe.k
[Apache-Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y83J.png)

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to AD over LDAP, you either specify the LDAP *DN* (e.g. CN=user,DC=domain) or the AD *UPN* (e.g. user@domain).

In your case, remove the domain from the LDAP DN:

```
ldapsearch -h IT.xxxx.COM -D "CN=user,DC=it,DC=xxxx,DC=com" -w Password -b base 'objectClass=*'
```

The domain is already represented by `DC=it,DC=xxxx,DC=com`.

Comment: I've already tried with ldapsearch -h IT.xxxx.COM -D "CN=user,DC=it,DC=domain,DC=com" -w Password -b base 'objectClass=*' but i always get ldap_simple_bind: Invalid credentials  --- 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090400, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e -

Comment: In this case, the user specified by the DN `CN=user,DC=it,DC=domain,DC=com` does not exist, *or* the password is incorrect. Usually in AD, users are not located beneath DC (`DC=`) objects  but beneath another container. Try `CN=user,CN=Users,DC=it,DC=domain,DC=com`

Comment: tried dapsearch -h IT.xxxx.COM -D CN=V*****,CN=Users,DC=it,DC=dom*****,DC=com -w Password -b base 'objectClass=*'  but stil Ivalid credentials. The java version with String username = "dom*****\\V******; works fine

Comment: Allright, that means the user is not located in the `CN=Users` container. It might be anywhere. You should either ask the AD admin for the tree structure, or simply use `user@domain.com` (or apparently even `domain\user`)

Comment: Tried with user@domain.com but invalid credentials. Can I see the tree directory structure with ApacheDirectoryStudio after I successfully authenticated ?

Comment: Yes you can! Try to find your user.

Comment: I think I've got it !!

With ApacheDirectoryStudio I've been able to see the full DN and then I put into the C variable:
static char *binddn ="CN=xxxxxx,OU=Users,OU=IT,DC=it,DC=xxxxx,DC=com";
and I authenticated !!

Thanks for your time